# Creating a form for a Tablet PC

Tags: c#, windows, forms, touch, tablet

I am in the middle of creating a form that will work with Tablet PCs. But right now i need to see what are the best practices that one can have when creating them. When i am creating forms i am referring to the forms where a  user fills in data presses next it is similar to a survey application.
Does anyone have any helpful links or even suggestions that will help me understand the best practices for tablet PCs?

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't directly C# related, I found it to be a fine example of how to do forms for Tablets in the manner you describe, where the user can hit the Next or Back button to navigate thru a form in a user-friendly environment: http://jqtouch.com/

I just started converting a site that was designed for Tablet users earlier today and managed to finish about a 20+ field form to the point where I'm ready to plug in the existing .NET form fields first thing on Monday. If I can, I'll post an example after it's ready to go

Answer (score -1):

Just create a next form & On Button_Click require.FormName & Form1.Visible=false
So a next form will open with different options,etc and the fist form will hide so it will look like a different page.

Comment: You are allowed to put advertising on your user profile page, but keep it out of your answers, or they will be deleted as spam.